# Problem in output specific values in array

Tags: bash

Does anyone know how to print values in array between two values？

For example:

```
array = (ha222 ha123 ha32 ha43 ha43 ha2342 ha4234)
```

I only want to print values between `ha123` and `ha2342`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
#index   0     1     2    3    4    5     6
array=(ha222 ha123 ha32 ha43 ha43 ha2342 ha4234)

$ echo ${array[@]:1:5} #print 5 items from array starting from index 1
ha123 ha32 ha43 ha43 ha2342
```

And if you want to automate this, then you have to loop throgh this array with something like this:

```
first='ha123'
last='ha2342'

for item in "${array[@]}"; {
    [[ $item == $first ]] && start=true
    [[ $start ]] && { [[ $item == $last ]] && { echo $item; break; } || echo $item; }
}
```

And this variant won't show anything if `last` var unset or incorrect:

```
start=
first='ha123'
last=''

for item in "${array[@]}"; {
    [[ $item == $first ]] && start=true
    [[ $start ]] && { [[ $item == $last ]] \
        && { newarr+=("$item"); echo "${newarr[@]}"; break; } \
        ||   newarr+=("$item"); }
}
```

Going further we can add some more checks to prevent loop start with wrong or unset initial values in `first` and\or `last` vars:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(ha222 ha123 ha32 ha43 ha43 ha2342 ha4234)

first='sad'
last=''

fail=
start=
mess=()
fun() {
    for item in "${array[@]}"; {
        [[ $item == $first ]] && start=true
        [[ $start ]] && { [[ $item == $last ]] \
            && { newarr+=("$item"); echo "${newarr[@]}"; break; } \
            ||   newarr+=("$item"); }
    }
}

[[ "${array[@]}" =~ ${first:-FAIL} ]] || { fail=True; mess+=("First item($first) incorrect"); }
[[ "${array[@]}" =~ ${last:-FAIL}  ]] || { fail=True; mess+=("Last item($last) incorrect"); }

[[ $fail ]] && printf '%s\n' "${mess[@]}" || fun # start only if $fail var unset
```

Looks like we can do it even without loop), using `BASH_REMATCH` like this:

```
re="$first.*$last"
[[ "${array[@]}" =~ $re ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
```

Combine with checks:

```
[[ "${array[@]}" =~ ${first:-FAIL} ]] || mess+=("First item($first) incorrect")
[[ "${array[@]}" =~ ${last:-FAIL}  ]] || mess+=("Last item($last) incorrect")
[[ "${array[@]}" =~ $first.*$last  ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH || printf '%s\n' "${mess[@]}"
```

Comment: but if I put the value in last variable which it doesnt exsit in array, it loops infinitely

Comment: @karrine it'll loop until the end of array not infinitely

Comment: @karrine, but you are right it's not correct, updated my answer to support this.

Comment: Thanks, $BASH_REMATCH is perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Translating the other answer from pseudocode to bash, you could find the element index in the array and get the subarray from those indexes:

```
arr_index() {
   local elem cnt
   cnt=0
   elem=$1
   shift
   while (($#)); do
       if [[ "$elem" == "$1" ]]; then break; fi;
       ((++cnt))
       shift
   done
   echo "$cnt"
}
array=(ha222 ha123 ha32 ha43 ha43 ha2342 ha4234)
first=$(arr_index ha123 "${array[@]}")
last=$(arr_index ha2342 "${array[@]}")
echo ${array[@]:$first:$((last - first + 1))}
# or:
echo ${array[@]:first:last - first + 1}
```

Comment: IMHO this is an overkill. I'm not new to bash, but it took some time to understand what's what.